# while true loop freezes up broswers javascript

Tags: javascript, image, loops, while-loop

so im trying to make the images change and make them into a loop and i came up with this script, and the problem i am having is that, when it change to the second picture the javascript would freeze up on me, I know it the while(true) part but i dont know how to fix it, please help.
 thanks you

```
var images = new Array();
images[0] = "image1.jpg";
images[1] = "image2.jpg";
images[2] = "image3.jpg";
setTimeout("changeImage()", 3000);
var x=0;

function changeImage()
{
    while(true){
        document.getElementById("img").src=images[x]
        x++;
    }

    if (x=2){
        x=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "hey doc, it hurts when I do this"

Comment: When will that value ever change?

Comment: There must be a variable terminal condition for the loop to end. As it has been pointed out, to avoid an endless loop do not put a constant into your loop condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I see what you're trying to do.

`while (true)` is going to loop forever *synchronously*. What you want is to continually change images every 3 seconds (*asynchronously*).

Try this:

```
var timeoutId = null;

function changeImage() {
  document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
  x = (x + 1) % images.length;
  timeoutId = setTimeout(changeImage, 3000);
}
```

This way, `changeImage` will not loop forever; but every time it's called it will schedule another call to `changeImage` in 3 more seconds. This asynchronous process will continue indefinitely (what you were trying to do with `while (true)`) until the user leaves the page or you choose to call `clearTimeout(timeoutId)`.

Note that you could also get rid of the global variable `x` by making it a parameter to `changeImage`, like this:

```
function changeImage(x) {
  document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
  timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    changeImage((x + 1) % images.length);
  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Even better would be to use setInterval().

Comment: That depends; the `setTimeout()` inside the function is unconditional and each invocation definitely takes less than three seconds.

Comment: @Jack: Sure, and if those are your criteria for when `setInterval` is preferable to `setTimeout` then by all means, use it. I suspect many others share your view, but you'd have a hard time convincing me one way or the other is actually better or worse. I think it's just a po-tay-to, po-tah-to thing. Preference aside, I will point out that my proposal to eliminate the need for `x` outside of `changeImage` only works with `setTimeout`. Maybe you think it's a dumb proposal. Again, I say it comes down to taste.

Comment: Nah, I don't think it's dumb; it's a pretty neat solution actually. I would have probably bound `x` to the function itself to accomplish the same thing =D

Comment: You would probably want to pull the document.getElementById out of the changeImage function as well, for efficiency.

Comment: @BigEd: Not a bad suggestion, although last I checked that method was absurdly fast on every major browser (probably internally just a hash lookup).

Comment: @BigEd: ...yeah, like millions of times per second. http://jsperf.com/finding-a-dom-needle-with-getelementbyid

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've *intentionally* created an infinite loop.

I'm not sure what other explanation you're after....

Your code will never reach the condition:

```
if (x=2)
```

because it never gets out of the loop. Provide some way to escape the loop. If your intention is to regularly cycle images then perhaps you should consider  getting the images on a timer.

Also, your code implies there are an infinite number of images.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser freezes up because JavaScript is single-threaded; it will ignore all inputs and events until the loop is done.

What you really want is something like this:

```
var x = 0; 
var nextImage= function () { 
    document.getElementById("img").src = images[x]; 
    x = (x + 1) % images.length;
}
setInterval(nextImage, 3000);
```

at each cycle, the code changes one image and quits, allowing other events to be handled.

BTW, I wasn't trying to write *good* JavaScript, just to answer your question.