# the page became unresponsive when the while loop is working

Tags: javascript, jquery

my page became unresponsive when my while loop is working

```js
$(".hidebutton").click(function () {
            var parented = $(".selected").data("id"); 
            var currentid = parented + 1; 
            while(true)
            {
                var chiledtrleft = $("tr[data-id='" + currentid + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left"); 
                var parentleft = $("tr[data-id='" + parented + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left"); 
                if (chiledtrleft <= parentleft) {
                    break; 
                }
               
                $("tr[data-id='" + currentid + "']> td:first-child").hide(); 
                // do shifting here

            }
        });
```

what is the problem in my code?

Comment: `true` is always `true` hence `while` loop will never end!

Comment: instead of true which one is better?

Comment: What does `$("tr[data-id='" + parented + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left")` return? Is `while` loop necessary to return expected result?

Comment: You're always comparing `padding-left` of 2 elements, but this is not the case to use a while true loop. If you want to do something if `chiledtrleft <= parentleft` or not, you just need an `if` statement. If this has to be checked all the time, then use `setInterval`.

Comment: @ guest i want the parented left value .so i ...

Comment: Javascript runs in single thread(main). Hence it will freeze the page if there is an infinite loop. For more information, refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425483/while-true-loop-freezes-up-broswers-javascript

Comment: Yes, what does `.css("padding-left")` return? A `String` or `Number`?

Comment: it is a number like 20px, 40px,....

Comment: Try using `parseInt()`; e.g., `var parentleft = parseInt($("tr[data-id='" + parented + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left")); var parentleft = parseInt($("tr[data-id='" + parented + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left")); if (chiledtrleft <= parentleft) {$("tr[data-id='" + currentid + "']> td:first-child").hide();}`.`while` loop does not appear to be necessary

Comment: @AndyRay They're comparing the value of the css property, not a jQuery object.  The problem is that it's probably returning a string like '10px' which makes the comparison lexicographical.  A `parseInt` will work.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is running indefinitely.  I see a few things wrong with your code.

```
var chiledtrleft = $("tr[data-id='" + currentid + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left"); 
var parentleft = $("tr[data-id='" + parented + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left");
```

Those lines will return strings that look like "10px" and not integers like "10".  You'll need to parse the int with the function `parseInt` if you want to compare them.

Your code is going to do a lexical comparison (alphabetical) which I suspect is part of the reason your if statement is failing.  You can fix this like so:

```
var chiledtrleft = parseInt($("tr[data-id='" + currentid + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left"));
var parentleft = parseInt($("tr[data-id='" + parented + "']> td:first-child").css("padding-left"));
```

Furthermore, you're not actually doing anything to the padding in the loop.  If the condition evaluates false, it'll continue evaluating false indefinitely.  You need to do something (I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish) to the padding.  I'm assuming the comment `//do shifting here` is meant to adjust the padding.  Implementing that and my above suggestion should fix your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Browser keeps executing a while loop  after you've clicked on a button, as your break condition is not fulfilled. Therefore it becomes unresponisve.

Comment: Browser becomes unresponsive because JS runs on single thread and running an infinite loop will block the thread.